# Formatting Joda LocalDate in JqGrid

Tags: jsp, datepicker, jqgrid, jodatime, jsp-tags

I'm trying to convert jodaDateFormat in my jqGrid.

The declaration in my Entity class is:

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
@DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)
@Column(nullable=false)
private LocalDate dateStart;
```

To see this date in the view, I try to insert in the tagx file this javascript conversion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
jodaLDFormatter = function (cellValue, options) {
    if(cellValue) {
        return $.datepicker.formatDate(
            'dd/MM/yyyy', 
            new Date(cellValue['year'], 
                    cellValue['monthOfYear']-1, 
                    cellValue['dayOfMonth']));
    } else {
        return '';
    }
};
```

In the JSP page I declare the column in this way:

```
<table:jqcolumn id="l_list_dateStart" property="dateStart" formatter="jodaLDFormatter"/>
```

but I obtain this: (from source of page)

```
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="NaN/NaN/NaNNaN" aria-describedby="l_list_dateStart">NaN/NaN/NaNNaN</td>
```

I don't want to convert every date in string for see it in jqGrid!

What's the right way?!

Comment: You will need to set the srcformat and newformat options in formatoptions. The default srcformat is ISO date (Y-m-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't pass the Joda object to the view. Probably you send from your controller a vector like `[day, month, year]`.

If my guess is correct, you can add this inside your `colmodel`:

```
formatter: 'date', srcformat:'dd/mm/yy', date:'true'
```